# User connection limit as concurrency limiting measure?

Tags: postgresql

I have large number of tasks (on separate machines in cloud) using one big postgres database. For illustration, every task reads some data for few seconds (up to a minute) and then processes them for a few minutes. But queries can be quite complex, so I definitely don't want them to run 100 at the same time.

Ideally, I would implement some distributed semaphore around DB access logic in the tasks themselves, but these can be tricky. My question is, can I do it "the easy way" and use postgres connection limit per user to do this? For example, I set connection limit 10 to the user they are all using, and simple retry logic (with some sleep) around opening the DB connection. This of course assumes, that every task is using short-lived connections (close after each query) to free them up for other workers.

I know there is small memory overhead (around 5MB) for every connection backend. But I did not find anything about overhead of opening&closing connections frequently, and maybe even refusing connections frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by Laurenz's answer, I investigated connection pooling, and this is in fact ideal solution for this problem. I have installed pgBouncer, set `pool_mode` to `statement` (since my queries are simple independent selects) and `pool_size` to desired number of concurrent queries. Works like a charm, only change needed in clients is change of port number (they connect to pgBouncer running on the same machine instead of DB directly). 
Only potential trouble with `statement` mode is you cant use `search_path` - your queries need to specify schemas in them.

Answer (score 1):

You can user the per-user connection limit for that, but I would only use it as a safety net. Retrying connections all the time is very expensive.

You should use a connection pool. Then the connection pool is the bottleneck, you don't have to retry connections, and your connection limit is automatically respected.

Comment: Thanks. Any details/source on "Retrying connections all the time is very expensive"?

Comment: It is a `fork` and a lot of setup on the database server side. This is well known, but I invite you to verify it by using `pgbench` with and without the `-C` option.